# How to separate out letters in a sentence using R

Tags: r

I have a character vector that is a string of letters and punctuation. I want to create a data frame where each column is made up of a letter/character from this string.

e.g.

```
 Character string = I WENT TO THE FAIR

 Dataframe = | I |   | W | E | N | T |   | T | O |   | T | H | E |   | F | A | I | R |
```

I thought I could do this using a loop with substr, but I can't work out how to get R to write into separate columns, rather than just writing over the previous letter. I'm new to writing loops etc so struggling a bit to get my head around the way in which to compose what I need.

Thanks for any help and advice that you can offer.

Best wishes,

Natalie

Comment: You want an empty data.frame as result? The letters are the column names?

Answer (score 2):

This should get that result

```
string <- "I WENT TO THE FAIR"
df <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(strsplit(string,""))), row.names = "1")
```

Comment: You could also change `row.names = "1"` to be `row.names = string`, if you wanted to preserve the original string as the row name.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. You're help is much appreciated!